# How do i use mysql operaor with minikube

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, devops, minikube, kubernetes-operator

I went through the mysql operator documentation on [github](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-operator) and i followed through but i kept getting this error

```
Patching failed with inconsistencies: (('remove', ('status', 'kopf'), {'dummy': '2022-07-14T15:51:30.145945'}, None),)
0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
Back-off restarting failed container
```

here are the kubernetes file  used

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysql/mysql-operator/trunk/deploy/deploy-crds.yaml

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysql/mysql-operator/trunk/deploy/deploy-operator.yaml

```
apiVersion: mysql.oracle.com/v2
kind: InnoDBCluster
metadata:
  name: mycluster
spec:
  secretName: mypwds
  tlsUseSelfSigned: true
  instances: 3
  router:
    instances: 1
```

I dont know what to do. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Is it important to use mysql from oracle - you might want to consider using (compatible) MariaDB

Comment: Seems like some cleanup issue. Could you try removing your PersistentVolumeClaims (and possibly also Persistent Volumes) and try again?

Comment: yea i agree with rafal, also look into finalizers. i believe you have a pv or pvc terminating and basically blocking each other. https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/05/14/using-finalizers-to-control-deletion/

Comment: @RafałLeszko  i got a new error    Patching failed with inconsistencies: (('remove', ('status', 'kopf'), {'dummy': '2022-07-18T01:03:09.536627'}, None),)
Back-off restarting failed container